# Draw a graph using Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am very new to tensorflow. I have installed Tensorflow CPU version and also installed python 3.5.2. I have also created a simple program using tensorflow like some addition of two numbers etc. Now i want to create a graphical program using python and tensorflow. Is it possible? any simple program will be helpful(like draw a line, draw a graph etc..). Kindly mention the steps. i have tried lots of examples but its not working.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

TensorFlow is not here to draw anything. Like, really not. It is built to compute stuff, over CPU and GPU and to give a Machine Learning library.

Now, you may have been confused because TensorFlow often mention "graphs". Those graphs are computational graphs, which is how each operations are linked one to another. In fact, "graphs" refers to a set of [vertice and edges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory), which can be drawn, but is not a "graphical" object in itself. Still, you can see this graph, generated by TensorFlow, thanks to [Tensorboard](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/summaries_and_tensorboard).

Now, what is totally possible is, in one hand to run intensive computations thanks to TensorFlow AND, in the other hand, another librarie to draw, plot etc...

The most famous/documented/used/best by far is [matplotlib, aka pyplot](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html). This is the lib to use, the lib to learn, as you will encounter it everywhere. In fact, I don't know any other lib.

Tell me if my answer is somehow off topic, or if you would like me to precise something.
Have fun!

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input. It means we can only compute through tensorflow? Like adding 2 numbers right? or many other complex computation.. not draw the graph right?

Comment: Way way more complex computation too, mostly matrix operation etc.
What you can see it the computational graph thanks to tensorboard

Comment: can u pls provide me one complex example so that i can run a see how it computes the complex operations. it will be very helpful for me. it will help me to understand tensorflow.

Comment: The best would be that you take a look at the official tutorials: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials

Comment: in the output here is a graph. how it so?

Comment: Its quite more complicated. I don't know your background so I can't really know where to start from. 
The fact is, tensorflow is meant to define a computational graph, and then to run it. Graph does not mean graphical. It is not an image. It is a set of operation linked together. The output is not a graph, still, if you get the code, you can generate the graph from it.